# Is the following matrix linearly independent or linearly dependent? Why or why not?

Tags: linear-algebra

For the following question, I'm getting mixed answers. When I do my usual calculation, to figure out if the only relationship between the vectors is the trivial one, I find that there are an infinite number of solution - in other words, the vectors of the matrix are linearly dependent. However, the example answer (from an online textbook) says it is linearly independent.

> 1.8 Example The rows of this matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&3&1&0\\0&-1&0&-2\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ form a linearly independent set. This is easy to check for this case but also recall that Lemma One.III.2.5 shows that the rows of any echelon form matrix form a linearly independent set.

Also, upon checking my answer using the following website's online computational tool, I find that it agrees with my answer, in that the matrix is linearly dependent: http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi

I would greatly appreciate a response as to what the correct answer is and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to know what you did exactly, but I suspect the issue lies here:

- The *rows* of the matrix are linearly independent.
- The *columns* of the matrix are linearly dependent.

Chances are you checked the latter, as this corresponds to solving the linear system typically assigned to a matrix.

Yet, it is the former that is asked in your exercise.
To answer this you need to consider a system of four equations with three unknowns (one for each *row*).

Comment: Ahh! You're absolutely correct. It makes sense, since the example does specify rows. Thank you!